# How to read list of schema files (.xsd) from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file from where I need to read schema file name (.xsd) and then I need to read these xsd file from a physical location to validate the xml against its schema.

**I can read only one schema file using doc selecting Single Node() property.**

How to read all schema file name (.xsd files) with the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` in under different tags?

XML file: [image: XML file]

Comment: What programming language is this about? What have you tried so far? Please post XML as text, not as an image.

Comment: I cannot add xml as text.
Basically in xml file on first tag <GeneralDocument> we have xsi:schemalocation attribute which i can read the schema file from it.
Now if i have same attribute xsi:schemalocation in dfferent child tags in the same xml file then how i will get the another schema name file from this child tag and xsi:schemalocation attribute?

Comment: I am using C# programming.
string schema=document.SelectingSingleNode("*").Attribute["attributeName"].Value;

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-6.0) instead of `SelectSingleNode`.